# Can't find pvr addons in XBMC

Tags: xbmc

I just upgraded my pc from xbmcbuntu 12.2 Frodo to xubuntu 14.04 and installed xbmc 13.1 Gotham on it. Xbmc runs fine, but I can't find any pvr addons, in fact I don't have any "Disabled addons" at all, like in Frodo. I have looked all over, but I can't find a way to add or enable any pvr client in xbmc. Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, I did:

```
sudo apt-get install xbmc-mediaportal-pvr
```

then restarted xbmc