# Xbmc PVR error, trying to enable IPTV

Tags: 14.04, xbmc, tv, mythtv

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, latest Beta version of xbmc, aka Kodi. Latest version of Mythtv [installed](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Trusty_Tahr_Installation). Xbmc's mythtv addon installed, aka mythbox.

Still I'm seeing this error

[image]

How to fix it?

I saw this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517735/cant-find-pvr-addons-in-xbmc). But there's nothing called `xbmc-mediaportal-pvr` in apt repo.

Comment: Are you sure that the mythtv add-on you're using is compatible with Kodi? And that it's in the Enabled Add-ons list and configured correctly? I'd expect some problems using a beta version..which is why I stick with the main releases of XBMC.

Comment: @douggro no configure button http://tinypic.com/r/2gwfhjn/8 xbmc crashes, kodi is working great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve the error, I had to add this to my sources

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jlbarriere68/ppa/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jlbarriere68/ppa/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main
```

and then `sudo apt-get install kodi-pvr-mythtv-helix`

to  enable  IPTV simple addon, I did `sudo apt-get install kodi-pvr-iptvsimple`

from terminal, I couldn't get  it to work when I installed it from XBMC's addon's page.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Is there no official mythtv add-on available from the MythTV Project for Kodi yet? I could never get mythbox to work on my XBMC installs..

Comment: @douggro nether do i, mythbox didn't work, I don't think that there are official plugins out there right now

Comment: @douggro i edited my answer to include how i installed iptv plugin if you're having troubles, still can't understand how to setup mythtv though, no luck on that but iptv is working